# Implication of 立ち去る versus 去る

Tags: word-choice, nuances

In the phrase:

> 先生が立ち去ると...

why would you choose to use 立ち去る rather than just 去る? Is there a possible ambiguity from using just 去る? Does it have a different nuance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- 立ち去る is to *walk* away on foot from some place. If you get on a car or train immediately after saying goodbye to someone, that's not 立ち去る.
- 去る has a broader sense, "to leave" in general. Depending on the context, it can mean something very strong, for example, quitting a company forever, parting with someone forever.

立ち去る and 去る are probably interchangeable in your case, but when you describe something that can happen everyday, 立ち去る would sound a bit safer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the dictionary, 立ち去る means to actually get up and leave a place:
たちさる【立（ち）去る】立ってその場所から去る
http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/136997/meaning/m0u/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E5%8E%BB%E3%82%8B/

So the meaning is slightly different than just 去る (to leave).

Comment: I don't think the verb 立ち去る indicate that a leaver was in a non-standing position before leaving. Rather the "立ち" part refers to the on-foot-ness as they leave.

Comment: The dictionary literally says "to stand up and leave" (立ってその場所から去る)

Comment: 「立ってその場から去る」 here does NOT mean 「立ち**上がって**その場から去る」, BUT 「 **立った状態で**その場から去る」. 日本語話者なら普通は誰でもそう読むと思いますが・・　(ところで GB さん ↓ もしかして間違って解答欄にコメント書いたんですか・・・？)

Comment: 如何にもその通りでございます。